# Do all Android devices have USB OTG support?

Tags: stock-android, usb-drivers, usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go, usb-mass-storage

I am using  **celkon A98**. The specification of my device says it does not have **USB OTG support** ..  I tried **OTG troubleshooter app**... it says USB host is supported ... Do I have **USB host functionality **or was that a bug in the **OTG troubleshooter app** ?
L

Comment: the manufacturer should make the `kernal` to support `OTG`

Answer (score 2):

No, not all Android devices have USB-on-the-go support. [GSMArena claims that your device doesn't](http://www.gsmarena.com/celkon_a98-5309.php), but they'll only be going on the specification.

The tool could be reporting that your phone has the software support for acting as a USB host, but unless the hardware also supports USB-OTG, that's not going to help you.

Comment: Actually all androd 3.0+ devices have the hardware facility ... @Dan Hulme

Comment: @Joe_Vj_95 That's quite a bold claim. I'd be interested to know where you heard it.

Comment: @DanHulme check Android official docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html: "USB accessory and host modes are directly supported in Android 3.1 (API level 12) or newer platforms"

Comment: @GuidoGarcía That doesn't say anything about the hardware, just that the OS supports it.