# How can I enable/add USB OTG support to my rooted and Cyanogenmod installed Huewei Honor 4x?

Tags: kernel, usb-on-the-go

I have tried stickmount but did not succeed in getting otg mounted. I basically want to use wireless mouse or keyboard. I think the kernel that is installed presently does not support otg. What is the way to add otg support like patching kernel and procedure needs to be followed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to flash a custom and compatible kernel. Usually there are multiple kernels to choose once CM is available for a device.

Comment: I learned that you need to have hardware support as well, for OTG to work. [Enabling OTG support in Micromax Canvas Nitro A310](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/103768)